# regular expression using oracle REGEXP_INSTR

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to use REGEXP_INSTR function in a query to search for any match for user input but I don't know how to write the regular expression that for example will match any value that includes the word car followed by unspecified numbers of letters/numbers/spaces and then the word Paterson. can any one please help me with writing this regEx?

Comment: we can help if you show some data and the expected output?

Comment: for example I want the expression to match 'this car belongs to Paterson and the other car belongs to someone else'

Comment: Please provide exact text which you have  and the expected output. Otherwise we might keep guessing as to what you need.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's break this down.

"any value that includes the word car"

I surmise from this that the word car doesn't need to be at the start of the string, therefore i would start the format string with...

```
'^.*'
```

Here the '^' character means the start of the string, the '.' means any character and '*' means 0 or more of the preceding character. So zero or more of any character after the start of the string.

Then the word 'car', so...

```
'^.*car'
```

Next up...

"followed by unspecified numbers of letters/numbers/spaces"

I'm guessing that unspecified means zero or more. This is very similar to what we did to identify any characters that might come before 'car'. Where the '.' means any character

```
'^.*car.*'
```

However, if unspecified means one or more, then you can use '+' in place of '*'

"then the word Paterson"

I'm going to assume that as this is the end of the description, there are no more characters after 'Paterson'.

```
'^.*car.*Paterson$'
```

The '$' symbol means that the 'n' of 'Paterson' must be at the end of the string.

Code example:

```
select
    REGEXP_INSTR('123456car1234ABCDPaterson', '^.*car.*Paterson$') as rgx
from dual
```

Output

```
       RGX
----------
         1
```